# Does "snapshot" command exist like in Linux Redhat?

Tags: snapshot

I used to use "snapshot" command to capture screen shots in the Linux Redhat environment. Is there the same or similar command with ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: There are many ways to take a screen shot from the command line. run `yum provides snapshot` to see which package provides that program in RHEL and we can see if it exists in Ubuntu and if not provide an alternate.

Comment: I wonder how redhat does let you take screenshots. Can you explain some more?

Comment: @MadMike - That question is off topic here ;) Ask in a RHEL support forums or run `yum provides snapshot`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am suggesting to be more precise about what he is trying to do in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I think this is relevant in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`scrot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot). It's available from the Software Center.

It has many features, but if you just want to take a screenshot, invoke `scrot` and an image file will be saved in the current directory.